# Gradle - globally define plugins repository proxy-cache for all projects

Tags: gradle

I need to globally set the plugin repositories for all Gradle projects. There is a way of doing that by adding the below section in `settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
      maven {
          url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins/'
          credentials {
              username = 'some-user'
              password = 'some-password'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

However, when I put this file in `~/.gradle/settings.gradle`, it doesn't seem to be working. I don't want to add such `settings.gradle` file in each project due to corporate reasons.

Is there a way of telling Gradle globally where to fetch all of the plugins?